# Best way to implement flexbox on HTML elements?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm relatively new to web design and have been playing around with flexbox. I'm curious what the best way to implement it is.

If I have a bit of code like this:

```
<body>
 <header>
     <h1>Page Header</h3>
 </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
     <li>Nav Thing 1</li>
     <li>Nav Thing 2</li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </body>
```

It it better to treat each kind of section of the page (the header and nav in this case) as it's own parent container and treat the contents of each section as the children containers. Or is it better to treat the whole document as the parent container?

[This](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) has been my main reference on flexbox, but I'm not finding much about this there.

Comment: How about these one?
http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Comment: Those are super helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do both as needed since flexboxes can also have flexboxes as children, that should reduce you need for non-semantic container elements.

Your code example looks a bit anemic, so good scenarios how to use flexboxes don't really come to mind and it largely depends on how you want to design your page anyway.

Re-orienting a multi-level nav bar either as sidebar or as top navigation depending on device orientation (media query) might be a decent case to gather experience.